# VSTS Azure web deployment different folder

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I am using VSTS and there is my repository with my Laravel web application. So I want to deploy my application to wwwroot but the "physical path relative to site root" must be set to "site\wwwroot\public" because my view is in the public directory.

I thought that everything was working finde till I did my second deployment and the files where now deployed to "site\wwwroot\public" so that my view now had to be "site\wwwroot\public\public".

Now I am looking for a way to specify a different deployment directory than the view directory.
This is what my settings currently look like:
[settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQUUT.png)

Comment: You could use Azure Power Shell  to modify virtual application directory.

Comment: So you mean that it sets the path to wwwroot then deploy it and then let it set it back to wwwroot/public?

Comment: Yes, you could create a Azure Power Shell task on VSTS, change directory what you need, then you could deploy your code to the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is right, you could use Azure Power Shell to append a new virtual application to the existing ones. Use following code.

```
# Example call: SetWebAppConfig MyResourceGroup MySite $ConfigObject
# https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/b2a3d67a90b7b2d673d68dab553f82e015333d10/PowerShell/HelperFunctions.ps1#L84-L87
Function SetWebAppConfig($ResourceGroupName, $SiteName, $ConfigObject)
{
    $WebAppApiVersion = "2015-08-01"
    Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/Config -Name $SiteName/web -PropertyObject $ConfigObject -ApiVersion $WebAppApiVersion -Force
}

Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

$website = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $websiteName
$virtualApplications = $website.SiteConfig.VirtualApplications

$hash = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

for ($j = 0; $j -lt $virtualApplications.count; $j++) {
    $entry = @{ virtualPath = $virtualApplications[$j].VirtualPath; physicalPath = $virtualApplications[$j].PhysicalPath }
    $hash.add($entry)
}
$newEntry = @{ virtualPath = "/$siteName"; physicalPath = "site\$siteName" }
$hash.add($newEntry)


$hashProps.VirtualApplications
$virtualApps = $website.SiteConfig.VirtualApplications.Add(@{ virtualPath = "/$siteName"; physicalPath = "site\$siteName" })
$props=@{
    virtualApplications = $hash.ToArray()
}

SetWebAppConfig $resourceGroupName $websiteName $props
```

Please refer to the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923540/set-azurermwebapp-changes-in-powershell-not-appearing-in-azure-portal).

Note: In VSTS, you could create a Azure Power Shell task.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try that later.

Is there a was to also change the path from the console of the web app?

Comment: Do you mean change it on Kudu?

Comment: Ok, It now works fine if I change it before and after. Thank you again.